# ¿Como conectar aplicación java con SQL de un servidor?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

MI problema consiste en que trato de poder conectar mi app de escritorio java con una SQL ya creada en el servidor [bidworker.net](http://www.bidworker.net:2082) pero cada vez que me conecto a este me rechaza la operación. Y me arroja un error.

```
  private static Connection cnx = null;


   public static Connection obtener() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
      if (cnx == null) {
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            cnx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bidworke_track_time", 
                    "bidworke_AP", "P]+#J9LC@ug1");
         } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new SQLException(ex);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new ClassCastException(ex.getMessage());
         }
      }
      return cnx;
   }

   public static void cerrar() throws SQLException {
      if (cnx != null) {
         cnx.close();
      }
   }
```

Error:

> sep 09, 2019 9:22:19 PM tracktime_.login_y_proyectos
>   jButton1ActionPerformed GRAVE: null java.sql.SQLException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   tracktime_.SQL_Conexion.obtener(SQL_Conexion.java:27) at
>   tracktime_.SQL_Conexion.obtener(SQL_Conexion.java:27)     at
>   tracktime_.login_y_proyectos.jButton1ActionPerformed(login_y_proyectos.java:194)
>     at tracktime_.login_y_proyectos.access$000(login_y_proyectos.java:22)
>     at
>   tracktime_.login_y_proyectos$1.actionPerformed(login_y_proyectos.java:75)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:355)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:822)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   tracktime_.SQL_Conexion.obtener(SQL_Conexion.java:24)     ... 39 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:244)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:305)  ... 54 more

Apoyo por favor.

Comment: `P]+#J9LC@ug1` es tu contraseña en bidworker? Yo en tu lugar la cambiaría de inmediato.

Comment: jajaja gracias pero ya la había cambiado antes de publicar.

Comment: Puedes explicar qué es "bidworker"? Intento entrar a la página para averiguar más pero me aparece como si estuviera en mantenimiento, o algo así...

Comment: Amigo este es el link www.bidworker.net primera vez que accedo a este servidor.

Comment: A eso me refiero: al entrar a esa página me sale mensaje: "Estamos desarrollado nuestra plataforma. Pedimos disculpas por las molestias ocasionadas". En algunas ocasiones, cuando el servicio es gratuito, bloquean el acceso a bases de datos desde fuera del sitio, pero eso tendrías que verlo directo con atención a clientes.

Comment: Amigo acabo de ingresar y me cargo la web pero persisto con el problema :(

Answer (score 1):

No he usado esa plataforma pero por lo que veo te sigues enlazando a tu servidor local

```
cnx=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bidworke_track_time", 
                "bidworke_AP", "P]+#J9LC@ug1");
```

No debería de ir `mysql://http://bidworker.net:XXX/... ?`

Comment: Amigo ya realice el ajuste en el link **jdbc:mysql://bidworker.net:2082/bidworke_track_time** pero pereciste el problema

Comment: Otro posible error es que tu servidor no acepte peticiones de tu IP pública, ademas Java es un lenguaje exacto por lo tanto debes especificar el www. y/o todo el link completo, como te lo especifique la documentación

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que esa conexión tenga algún método adicional de seguridad (filtro IP, certificado, etc)
Por otro lado, no publiques contraseñas reales (si la es) en este foro.

Comment: Amigo voy a tener que investigar mas de este servidor porque primera vez que trabajo con y estoy perdido :(.